# Parametric Equations: Having trouble with finding two tangents (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, parametric

curve C defined by these parametric equations

$x = t^3 - 3t^2$

$y = t^3 - 3t$

I need to find the equations of two tangents at the point $(-4,2)$

I have attempted to solve this problem myself but I got stuck.

Here is what I've done so far:

1) Found out that t came out to be $t = 2$ and $t = -1$

2) When I plugged $t = 2,-1$ into $dy/dx, t=2$ comes out to be undefined

3) $dy/dx = (3t^2-3)/(3t^2-6t) = (t^2-1)/(t^2-2)  $

*Re-submission of my question, I hope I did the right format this time*
Thank you

Comment: Try to think about what an infinity slope means...

Comment: @Resubmission2 hope the simplification ok

Answer (score 0):

The curve is self intersecting. So at one point ( 2.-1) there are two slopes.

For t= 2, slope is 3/2

For t= -1 ,slope is 0

So equation of first tangent is $$ (y+1)/(x-2) = 3/2 $$

and  equation of second  tangent is $$ (y+1)/(x-2) = 0 ,  y=-1. $$